# When I try to run flutter doctor or any flutter command, its giving error

Tags: flutter

When I try to run flutter doctor or any flutter command, it doesn't run and giving me this error. I've even deleted `.gitconfig` file from my system but still having same issue. I am using Flutter on my window pc Window 10

```
fatal: bad config line 1 in file .git/config
Updating flutter tool...

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Failed to send crash report. Server responded with HTTP status code 400
Crash report written to C:\Users\DTI-3\flutter_03.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
```

Comment: Reinstall git and check again.

Comment: I've reinstalled git but again same issue.

Comment: Please put the content of this file :  .git/config

Comment: I've deleted this file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've  deleted the **config** file from `C:\flutter\.git` flutter folder and tried with `flutter doctor` command. its working fine for me now. Earlier I was trying to make it run by deleting config file from another location, delete the file from flutter folder(flutter sdk path).